# Проблема с установкой Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

При установке произошел сбой с ошибкой[image: team explorer for microsoft visual studio 2015 update 3 ctp 1]

Удалял x86 Redistributable-пакет Visual Studio 2015, загружал [vc_redist.x86.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145), устанавливал не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Файл журнал](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2uKHFTccFnWek9iTFV4c18wZjg)

Comment: Веб установочник или с образа ставите? При проблемах рекомендуется попробовать поставить с образа

Comment: Попробую, напишу что получилось.

Comment: Не помогло, все по прежнем.

Comment: Пробовали решение отсюда? https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/271809/

Comment: операционная система х86 разрядная?

Comment: @Monk да скрин прикрепил,  там видно файли разного размера все ок

Comment: @Антон операционная система х64 разрядная

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все перепробовал, антивирус отключил файлы обновлял, ничего не помогло. Переустановил windows первым делом поставил visual studio, установилась и работает отлично.

Comment: И в чём разница между той виндой, что была и той, на которой встало?

Comment: @AK тот самый диск c windows